# Can't save video on Raspberry PI by using python with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, python-2.7, raspberry-pi

```
import cv
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(8,100)
out = cv2.VideoWriter('/home/pi/Desktop/output.mp4',cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC('D','I','V','X'),20.0,(640,480))
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
        frame = cv2.flip(frame,0)
        out.write(frame)
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(10) == 27: 
            break
cv2.VideoCapture(0).release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This code worked but it never stopped and no video file had been saved. Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do the frames show up on the screen? Are the frames exactly 640x480 pixels? What happened when you pressed Escape?

Comment: @w.m Sorry i just saw the comment. Yes, the frames showed up on the screen and it was exactly 640*480. When i pressed ESC, an error occurred. It displayed that cv2.VideoWriter object has no attribute 'release'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both release() calls can be removed.

```
cv2.VideoCapture(0).release()
```

would call release() on a new VideoCapture, what you meant was `cap.release()`.

For the VideoWriter, the release method doesn't exist - you don't have to care about releasing the VideoWriter or VideoCapture in Python. They will be released when their object is destroyed at the end of your program.

Comment: Thank you for answering me. I tried remove this line, but a new error occurs. "object has no attribute 'destroyAllWindows'"

Comment: And when I used "DestroyWindow('frame')", it had the same problem.

Comment: My spelling mistake. But I typed the right version in my script while having this problem.

Comment: And you corrected it to Window_S_, too? OpenCV does have a destroyAllWindows() method, and you are correct to call it there.

Comment: Yes,"cv2.destoryAllWindows()". It won't work, and shows object has no attribute 'destoryAllWindows'. The version of python and opencv i used are 2.7.3 and 2.3.1.

Comment: You are still spelling it incorrectly. Please refer to my last comment, and the OpenCV documentation, until you get it right. StackOverflow is not a spell checker.

Comment: "you don't have to care about releasing the VideoWriter or VideoCapture in Python. They will be released when their object is destroyed at the end of your program."




what if your program dose not terminate? Do you mean the resources are released when the reference to the object is lost and it is garbage collected. I cant find any mention of this in the docs. 

I am able to call release() on the VideoWriter in windows but in raspbian linux it leads to an error.

Comment: Doc on VideoCapture::Release states: "The methods are automatically called by subsequent VideoCapture::open() and by VideoCapture destructor." VideoWriter::Release is not documented. Use the del statement if you want to release the resources early.